# I can't properly set one matrix variable to another inside of the for loop

Tags: c++

With :

```
ifstream cin ("cowsignal.in") ;
ofstream cout ("cowsignal.out") ;
int n, m, k ;
cin >> n >> m >> k ;
char paper[n][m] ;

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
        cin >> paper[i][j] ;
    }
}

char ans[k*n][k*m] ;

for (int i=0; i<k*n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<k*m; j++) {
        ans[i][j] = paper[j/k][i/k] ;
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<k*n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<k*m; j++) {
        cout << ans[i][j] ;
    }
    cout << endl ;
}
return 0 ;
```

and an input of :

```
XXX.
X..X
XXX.
X..X
XXX.
```

I was expecting the result to be :

```
XXXXXX..
XXXXXX..
XX....XX
XX....XX
XXXXXX..
XXXXXX..
XX....XX
XX....XX
XXXXXX..
XXXXXX..
```

I got a different solution. Trying to find that problem, I added :

```
cout << ans[0][7] << paper[0][7/2] ;
```

And found that it hasn't been set correctly in the second for loop. I cannot figure out my problem.

Comment: You've swapped i and j .

Comment: maybe its better to choose different name for your file stream , with that names your code is ambiguous to read